# How do I get delete programs off of my computer?

Tags: command-line, installed-programs

**I thought I deleted some old programs but I was wrong and now my computer is low on memory.**

*Yes, the old case of I thought I deleted that but I actually didn't.*

I need to preform a system update on a bunch of my programs and I need about a gigabyte of memory but I have less, like way less. Most of the programs are video games my brother had downloaded a long time ago but we not longer play. How do I delete them off my computer, completely?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the package names, you can just run

```
apt purge packagename
```

to get a list off all installed programs, run:

```
dpkg --list
```

If you're still not sure, then use the GUI software center.

Comment: Other alternative to view which programs you have installed is to open Synaptic and applying a filter on it.

Comment: It all depends on how they were installed. "my brother had downloaded a long time ago" doesn't give me confidence that the games were installed using the packaging system. Were they?

Comment: Redbob--Why not post that as an answer with a screenshot or two? NerdOdLinux--You could point out in your answer that deleting stuff of off Disk doesn't free up RAM.

Comment: I think OP is talking about disk space, not RAM.